# error:expected unqualified-id before '=' token

Tags: c++, linux, g++

I keep getting this error while working with g++.

Here's the line of code in question:

```
Register register = new Register(til_amt, num_ones);
```

Here's the header definition:

```
Register(int, int);
```

Here's the implementation definition:

```
Register::Register(int amt, int ones)
{
    init();

    til_amt += amt;
    num_ones += ones;
}
```

The init() function is defined inline and simply sets the fields to 0. I've isolated the issue to these lines of code, and I've searched all over stackoverflow/google and can't seem to solve the problem. I even tried splitting up the object instantiation into 2 lines, but that didn't work either.

Comment: `register` is probably a keyword. I don't remember if it is defined in the standard, but at least certain compilers treat it as such.

Comment: @Matthew Freilhofer.  What James Root is saying is that all you need to do is change register to another variable name(that isn't a C++ keyword). So just change it to register1 or something...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`register` is a keyword. It cannot be used as a variable.

From the C++ Standard:

> **7.1.1 Storage class specifiers** [dcl.stc]
>
> 1 The storage class specifiers are
>
> ```
>    storage-class-specifier:  
>       register
>       static
>       thread_local
>       extern
>       mutable
> ```

Answer (score 1):

`register` is a keyword, so you can't use it as a variable name. Rename it to anything else and it should work.

It is supposed to hint to the compiler that the variable can be stored in a register, but it looks like most compilers will decide this for themselves (sort of like `inline`, although `inline` has more meaning).